# getAppHomePath() seems to throw a wrong path in Simulator?

Tags: codenameone

I have a problem with the getAppHomePath() Method, this one returns "file://home/" in the debugger, then afterwards i get a FileNotFoundException.

Code where it throws that Exception:

```
fileName = "100004_2016-06-29.jpg"
appHomePath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
img = Image.createImage(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(appHomePath + fileName));
```

ExceptionMessage:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\xyz\.cn1\file___home_100004_2016-06-29.jpg (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
```

so it seems that it adds this prefix "file___home_" which corrupts the Path, i have definitely a file "100004_2016-06-29.jpg" stored under that path.

The snippet which creates that file under that path is below:

```
img = Image.createImage(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(filePath));
OutputStream os = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(newFileName);
ImageIO.getImageIO().save(img, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 1.0f);
```

the filePath variable is returned by the ImageGallery, so its something under %TEMP%.

Anyway Storing a File works, Reading does somehow not.

Am i am missing something or is there really a bug in the Simulator Code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you mixed usage of the [Storage & FileSystemStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) which are two very different classes. Unfortunately the simulator maps `Storage` to roughly the same location as it maps the `FileSystemStorage` which is probably something we need to fix to avoid such cases.

You need to pick one API and use that. `ImageIO` works with `FileSystemStorage` so you need absolute files for that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it doesnt need the AppHomePath, the fileName is enough.

So simple to fix, but yeah sometimes its in the details...